# How to write this python code in map reduce or spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, xml-parsing, mapreduce, hdfs

I have the below code that parses the values from the xml file. Now i am looking for its equivalent in map reduce or spark. I am trying if we could do the same in map reduce or spark. Any algo or brief idea can help.

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
#import re

f1=open('FMI_observations_weather_cities_simple.xml','r') 
s=BeautifulSoup(f1,'lxml')## make a soup object
#print(s.prettify())## this will print it in a good format
x=s.find_all('wfs:member') #find all the elements of wfs:member tags ### find all the records of wfs:member
count=0
ll=[] ### list to contain the values
for l in x:# extracting the four useful variables that are present in the member element block
    coordinat=l.find('gml:pos')
    ts=l.find('bswfs:time')
    measure=l.find('bswfs:parametername')
    mea_value=l.find('bswfs:parametervalue')
#    ll.
    ll.append([coordinat.get_text(),ts.get_text(),measure.get_text(),mea_value.get_text()])## adding the values to the list as a list.
    print(coordinat.get_text(),ts.get_text(),measure.get_text(),mea_value.get_text())# printing each list
```

```html
-<wfs:member>


-<BsWfs:BsWfsElement gml:id="BsWfsElement.1.1.4">


-<BsWfs:Location>


-<gml:Point gml:id="BsWfsElementP.1.1.4" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4258" srsDimension="2">

<gml:pos>60.38690 22.55183 </gml:pos>

</gml:Point>

</BsWfs:Location>

<BsWfs:Time>2017-01-17T08:00:00Z</BsWfs:Time>

<BsWfs:ParameterName>T</BsWfs:ParameterName>

<BsWfs:ParameterValue>-4.5</BsWfs:ParameterValue>

</BsWfs:BsWfsElement>

</wfs:member>
```

Comment: how far have you made it so far? show us and then we can help. also state what this code does line-by-line

Comment: I havent tried it. but yes i ll edit and put comments in the code.